# I need to access a private Fargate task behind a private ALB,how can i access my task through Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

I need to access a private Fargate task behind a private ALB,how can i access my task through Lambda?How can I use an API gateway in this flow or its better to access directly through AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Editing this based on conversation...

You dont need API gateway for this. Since your lambda and service can reside in the same VPC. All you need to do is

1. Create the lambda inside the VPC/private subnet
2. Find the Route 53 entry for your service Task
3. Use this in the lambda
4. Of course don't forget to set IAM roles to allow lambda to access this service.

Comment: Thanks Sid.But our ALB and Tasks are in private subnet and API Gateway doesnt provide a way to connect to Private ALB,i guess it allows private connection only with NLB.In our solution we have lots of lambdas,which will connect to these private tasks,so we are looking for a optimum approach.

Comment: If your lambda is running in the same account then actually you dont need API gateway. All you need is to do is run the lambda in the same VPC/subnet and use the route 53 entry for the service to access it.

Comment: We want to avoid running Lambda in VPC since it doesnt scale well due to ENI limitations.